# Rectangling the rectangle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, recreational-mathematics, discrete-geometry, tiling

There is a classic problem of 'squaring the square', or constructing a [perfect squared square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square#Perfect_squared_squares), which is a [unit square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_square) cut into a [finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set) number of smaller [squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square) whose sidelengths are all different. We [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14916/284973) that these sidelengths must be [rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) so that we need only look for [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) [tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems); and it turns out [solutions](http://www.squaring.net/sq/ss/spss/spss.html) do exist to this problem (example shown below). A slightly more general (and much easier) [problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectRectangle.html) which also has [solutions](http://www.squaring.net/sq/sr/spsr/spsr.html) is to look for [rectangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle) that can be divided into distinct-sized squares.

A natural generalization is then to look for rectangles which can be tiled by different-sized [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)) rectangles. Obviously we should ask that our rectangle not be square, but indeed for any perfect squared square, we could simply [scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry)) it by an appropriate factor to create a dissection of *any* rectangle. Thus we could ask that at least one rectangle have a *different* [orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(geometry)) to the rest, and as far as I can see this makes the problem harder, and I have not found a solution or way of approaching it. It seems interesting to know though which rectangles permit such a tiling.

Thus I have the following ***question***: Is it possible to divide any non-square rectangle into a finite number of rectangles all of different sizes such that *all* rectangles (including the tiled rectangle) are similar, and such there is a pair of rectangles oriented [perpendicularly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpendicular)? If not, which rectangles permit such a dissection? In such a dissection (if one exists), must all of the rectangles be rational scalings of each other?

---

*Lowest-order perfect squared square*

$\hskip2in$[image: Squared square]

Comment: "different sized congruent rectangles" is a contradiction in terms. If two geometric figures are congruent, then they are the same size.

Comment: I guess OP meant similar rectangles. I'd guess it should be possible to demonstrate that a $1:\pi$ rectangle doesn't subdivide, but I don't have a specific proof idea, besides perhaps somehow looking at the field extension $\mathbb Q[\pi]/\mathbb Q$ as an infinite-dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I certainly did mean similar. I don't know how that got through.

Comment: @MvG I wonder if [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14878/cutting-a-unit-square-into-smaller-squares/14916#14916) sort of idea could be used to prove that the sides must be rationally related?

Comment: @Anon: Perhaps; it's too late here for me to think this through clearly. During the day I started a draft which might be used to prove that any path along diagonals has to use rectangles of one orientation only. But it's far from clear that one can go from one corner of the big rectangle using only diagonals of the small ones. So one would have to argue about the extra corner coordinates one would introduce even if following a rectangle edge, which complicates matters.

Comment: @MvG That's an interesting idea. At least such a proof would tell us *something*, namely that if we follow the diagonals in such a dissection then we get to an edge of the big rectangle, not a corner (unless I'm misunderstanding your comment). Perhaps this would allow us to establish bounds on the number of rectangles used, which might be useful? I'm not really sure.

Comment: It might be worth having a look at the paper, Freiling, Laczkovich, and Rinne, Rectangling a rectangle, Discrete Comput. Geom. 17 (1997) 217-225, MR1424825 (97j:52024), and also Prasolov and Skopenkov, Tiling by rectangles and alternating current, J Combin Theory Ser A 118 (2011) 920-937, MR2763046 (2012c:05079).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Those papers look very interesting. I'll take a bit to look through them.

Comment: At least to me it appears there are two ways to understand your question. Are you looking for *any* rectangle and a way to tile it in a self-similar fashion? Or are you looking for a way which will be able to generate a self-similar tiling for *any* rectangle? In the former case, you could pick an aspect ratio to suite your needs, while in the latter case you have to accomodate arbitrary ratios. My comments with $1:\pi$ and so on were aimed at the second interpretation, while the currently accepted example goes for the first.

Comment: @MvG I'm wondering which rectangles permit such a tiling. I'd be happy to accept a more general answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one example: You can tile an $18\times29$ rectangle with an $18\times9$, an $8\times4$, a $10\times20$, and an $8\times16$. The four tiles are rectangular, similar, of different sizes, with the first two oriented vertically, the other two, horizontally.

EDIT:

It appears that we want the big rectangle similar to the smaller ones. This can be achieved as follows. Let $k=\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}$. Then the four rectangles $(k+2k^3)\times(1+2k^2)$, $(k+k^3)\times(k^2+k^4)$, $k^3\times k^2$, and $k^3\times k^4$ tile a $(k+2k^3)\times(1+3k^2+k^4)$ rectangle. The big rectangle is similar to the others, since the equation $k(k+2k^3)=1+3k^2+k^4$ reduces to $k^4-2k^2-1=0$, or $(k^2-1)^2=2$, which is true.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. +1. I realise that I mustn't have written my question clearly enough though, because I actually wanted all of the tiling rectangles to be similar to the big rectangle also. I've edited my question to make it more clear. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: I was hoping for a non-trivial extension to squaring the square, where we tile a square with different-sized copies of *itself*.

Comment: You want it, you got it.

Comment: Nice answer! This is interesting.

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer! I just verified the tiling, and I tried to submit an edit with a paint drawing of it but it was rejected. I feel it would improve the answer, though, since it would mean that people wouldn't have to draw the tiling themselves to verify it. Thanks anyway.